# jQuery validationengine IE7 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-validation-engine

I am facing an issue with jquery validationengine plugin. The error is for IE7 browser only. Works fine on IE8, Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.

Here is what I am getting on IE7 - 
error : jQuery.validationEngine rules are not loaded, plz add localization files to the page.

```
Code :
<script src="js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#frm_contactus").validationEngine({promptPosition : "topLeft"});
});
</script>
```

I did some debugging using firebug. All the required JS files are loaded properly.

Comment: I have updated the question. Added some part of the code. Please check.

Comment: Did you download and include all the files with the `validationEngine`?

Comment: Yes. Works fine for Firefox, chrome, safari, IE8. But does not work on IE7.

Comment: Updated the validationEngine library. Replaced old JS files with new one. Working fine now !