# crazy Unspecified Error warning in IE (w jQuery).. but disappears when reloaded

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, unspecified

Not sure what all to supply except that I'm using IE8, and when in IE8 Browser Mode with IE8 Document mode, all is well. However, when I'm in IE7 Browser Mode (with ie7 doc mod), or in IE8 mode with IE7 Document Mode I get a silly error stating 'Unspecified Error'

The strange part, is that when I reload the page, it's gone and all the other trailing JS works just fine... so I don't have a lot to troubleshoot I feel.

The unminified version of jQuery is linked up and IE's 'amazing' debugging gives me line 2321, which is

```
ret = elem.getAttribute( name );
```

Just curious if anyone else has ever had similar scenarios.

I will be trying to find what the problem is with a First-time page load / IE7 / elem.getAttribute / jQuery; but that may be a bit broad... or even too specific ironically.

Comment: Is that line being run after the page has loaded?

Comment: well, whatever is indirectly referencing or calling that line is being run after page load. It should be anyways. I don't have any JS method being called prior to $(document).ready(

Comment: Fixed, thanks...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152580/jquery-validationengine-ie7-issue?rq=1